# Best way to save a Parent object

Tags: nhibernate

Just wondering what's the best-practice for saving a Parent that ordinarily contains a collection of Child objects (many-to-many in my case), but that collection in the Parent is currently set to null because it hasn't been loaded?

In my case, the Parent is passed to my service layer from a Web page. The web page has only populated the Parent's simple attributes from a form.

I know there are several Child objects linked to the Parent in the database, but the 'children' property is currently null.

If I save the Parent, even though my  of Children is set to cascade="none", when I save Parent, all the links are deleted (I can even see the delete statements NHibernate issues in the logs).

I can think of several ways to solve this:

1) Load the children seperately and then set the Parent's child collection to them and then save the parent (works but this is an additional trip to the database).

2) Issue an update on ONLY the simple properties using HQL or Native SQL.

Update: I'm not sure my cascade behaviour is working properly actually. From the docs, it suggests that NHibernate won't mess with my collection unless cascade is set to save-update, all-delete-orphan etc. But this is my mapping

(from Order.hbm.xml)

```
<bag name="OrderItems" table="order_item" cascade="none" lazy="true">
  <key column ="order_id" />
  <many-to-many class="MenuItem" column="item_id"/>
</bag>
```

When Order.OrderItems is null, and I save my Order object using SaveOrUpdate(Order), it definately deletes the collection. I want them to be preserved. Is my configuration wrong or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't actually use the real Parent object for passing data from UI to the service layer. You could instead implement a lightweight class ([Data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) that would contain just those basic properties and then pass it to the service tier and populate (either manually or using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)) the parent's properties.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did consider that, although to be honest I'd prefer only to have one set of domain objects I think. I've worked on large projects (Java) where maintaining DTOs have become a bit of a nightmare to maintain (keeping them in sync with the entities). At the moment, I have solved my problem using an HQL update 'query' that only touches the objects I care about at that point. It's still quite neat although I am sure there must be a flag in NHibernate to do what I want. Thanks again

Comment: Well it's certainly not mandatory to use DTOs everywhere but just where it makes most sense.